# CFMutableAttributedString crashing when running on device (EXC_BAD_ACCESS)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code:

```
NSString *name = @"some text goes in here";

        CFStringRef string =  (__bridge CFStringRef) self.highlightItem_.comment;
        CFMutableAttributedStringRef comment = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
        CFAttributedStringReplaceString (comment ,CFRangeMake(0, 0), string);

        CGColorRef blue =[UIColor colorWithRed:128/255.f green:203/255.f blue:255/255.f alpha:1.0].CGColor;
        CGColorRef gray =[UIColor colorWithWhite:153/255.f alpha:1.0].CGColor;

        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(comment, CFRangeMake(0, [name length]),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, blue);
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(comment, CFRangeMake([name length],  [self.highlightItem_.comment length] - [name length]),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, gray);

        CTFontRef nameFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)kProximaNovaBold, 15.0f, nil);
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(comment,CFRangeMake(0, [name length]),kCTFontAttributeName,nameFont);

        CTFontRef commentFont = CTFontCreateWithName((__bridge CFStringRef)kProximaNova, 15.0f, nil);
        CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(comment, CFRangeMake([name length],  [self.highlightItem_.comment length] - [name length]),kCTFontAttributeName,commentFont);

        CGContextSaveGState(context);
        CGRect captionFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width - 80, commentHeight);
        CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(comment);
        CGMutablePathRef captionFramePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathAddRect(captionFramePath, NULL, captionFrame);

        CTFrameRef mainCaptionFrame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, 0), captionFramePath, NULL);

        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformIdentity);
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 70, self.imageHeight_ + commentHeight + 20);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

        CTFrameDraw(mainCaptionFrame, context);
        CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        CFRelease(framesetter);
        CGPathRelease(captionFramePath);
```

I am not sure why when I run it on the simulator it all worked fine, but when I run it on the device, it crashes on this line:

```
CFAttributedStringSetAttribute(comment, CFRangeMake(0, [name length]),kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, blue);
```

any idea why?

Comment: I deleted my answer, I didn't see that you was already taking the CGColor attribute from UIColor.

Comment: what iOS does run on the simulator or on the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that I didn't retain my CGColor. If I put CGColorRetain then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't

```
CFMutableAttributedStringRef comment = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
CFAttributedStringReplaceString (comment ,CFRangeMake(0, 0), string);
```

read

```
CFMutableAttributedStringRef comment = CFAttributedStringCreateMutable(
    kCFAllocatorDefault, 
    CFAttributedStringGetLength(string));
CFAttributedStringReplaceString(comment,
    CFRangeMake(0, CFAttributedStringGetLength(string)), 
    string);
```

?